# Responsive CSS link not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following meta data in my index.php file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0,
    minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

I also have the following css links in my index.php file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main_styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:320px;)
    and (max-width:480px;)" href="css/main_mobile.css" />
```

The first css link picks up just fine (`css/main_styles.css`) but the second (`css/main_mobile.css`) does not pick up at all when i resize my browser window.

I've triple checked the syntax here and cannot find any errors.

What could be causing the second css determined by viewport width to not be picked up?

I'm trying a different approach to using `@media` in my css file itself as it makes for a lengthy file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:320px;)
    and (max-width:480px;)" href="css/main_mobile.css" />
```

change to (no semi colon after min-width and max-width value)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:320px)
    and (max-width:480px)" href="css/main_mobile.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:768px)
    and (max-width:1024px)" href="css/main_tablet.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:480px)
    and (max-width:768px)" href="css/small_screen.css" />



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:320px)
    and (max-width:480px)" href="css/small_screen.css" />
```